# package-lock.json in npm workspaces

Tags: npm

Given an npm workspace with the following structure

```
workspace
    package.json
    packages
        package-a
            package.json
        package-b
            package.json
```

When I run an install command in package-a this will generate a package-lock.json file in the root of the workspace but not in the package.json file itself.

Is there a way to also generate it in the packages?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible for example like this:

```bash
npm i emoji-picker-react -w packages/deepcase
```

This command updates `packages/deepcase/package.json` and `package-lock.json` in root folder.

```bash
(cd packages/deepcase && npm i --package-lock-only --workspaces false)
```

This command updates `packages/deepcase/package-lock.json`.

Comment: This does not work, if the workspace depends on other packages which are not yet in registry, e.g. packages which are in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, running `npm install` within that package directory should do the job. But as you said that this is creating a global package-lock.json. This might be because the package you are installing might be specifying the global path using the `prefix` field.
The "prefix" field, specifies the location where the package's dependencies should be installed.

So one thing you can do is to go to the `package.json` in package-a and then either remove the `prefix` field from the package.json file OR set its value as following :

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "prefix": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now when you run `npm install` it should install the packages locally and make a local 'package-lock.json`.

Comment: This only places the node_modules folder in package-a. I only care about the lock file since I am not committing the node_modules anyway.

Comment: @ArwedMett Got it! But did it put the lock file in package-a as well? Or is it still global?

Comment: that is the issue. It is in the directory of the workspace, but I want it in the packages. I want to reuse them and only use the workspace feature for working on all packages at once.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the **lerna** tool to manage your workspace and install dependencies in each package. you can generate package-lock.json files in each package in your workspace.

The Original Tool for JavaScript `Monorepos`. `Monorepo` means `a repository with multiple packages`.

[lerna.js.org](https://lerna.js.org/)

I hope this answer will show you the right direction.

Comment: Hmm, I saw that but I thought this might work out of the box too.